# Numpy array slicing transposes internal data

Tags: python, c, arrays, numpy, slice

I am writing a C extension that shall deal with numpy arrays. I have written a function to read and output the numpy array. Using it, I noticed a weird behavior that appears when I use slicing in the input array.

The C function to read the (boolan) array:

```
char **pymatrix_to_CarrayptrsChar(PyArrayObject *arrayin) {
    char **result, *array;
    int i, n, m, j;

    n = arrayin->dimensions[0];
    m = arrayin->dimensions[1];
    result = ptrvectorChar(n, m);

    array = (char *) arrayin->data; /* pointer to arrayin data as int */
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      result[i] = &array[i * m];
    }
    printArrChar(result, n, m);
    return result;
}
```

`ptrvectorChar` is a function for memory allocation:

```
char **ptrvectorChar(long dim1) {
    char **v;
    if (!(v = malloc(dim1 * sizeof(char*)))) {
        PyErr_SetString(PyExc_MemoryError,
              "In **ptrvectorChar. Allocation of memory for character array failed.");
        exit(0);
    }
    return v;
}
```

And printing is done with:

```
void printArrChar(char **arr, int dim1, int dim2) {
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < dim1; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < dim2; j++) {
            printf("%i ", arr[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

My python script for reproducing the error is:

```
import numpy as np
import MyExtension
np.random.seed(1)

x = np.array((1,1,1,1,1,1)).astype(bool)
a = np.round(np.random.rand(trialNr, lakeNr)).astype(bool)
aSlicing = a[:, x]

print("a:")
print(a + 0)

print("aSlicing:")
print(aSlicing + 0)

print("C output for a:")
MyExtension.MyFunction(a)

print("C output for aSlicing:")
MyExtension.MyFunction(aSlicing)
```

Output is:

```
a:
[[0 1 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 1 0 1]
 [0 1 0 1 0 1]
 [0 0 1 1 0 1]
 [1 1 0 0 0 1]
 [0 0 1 1 1 0]
 [1 1 0 1 1 1]
 [0 1 0 0 1 0]
 [0 0 0 1 0 0]
 [0 0 1 0 1 1]]

aSlicing:
[[0 1 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 1 0 1]
 [0 1 0 1 0 1]
 [0 0 1 1 0 1]
 [1 1 0 0 0 1]
 [0 0 1 1 1 0]
 [1 1 0 1 1 1]
 [0 1 0 0 1 0]
 [0 0 0 1 0 0]
 [0 0 1 0 1 1]]

C output for a:
0 1 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 1 0 1 
0 1 0 1 0 1 
0 0 1 1 0 1 
1 1 0 0 0 1 
0 0 1 1 1 0 
1 1 0 1 1 1 
0 1 0 0 1 0 
0 0 0 1 0 0 
0 0 1 0 1 1 

C output for aSlicing:
0 0 0 0 1 0 
1 0 0 0 1 0 
1 0 1 0 1 1 
0 0 0 0 0 1 
0 1 0 0 0 1 
0 1 1 1 0 1 
1 0 1 0 0 0 
0 0 0 1 1 1 
0 1 0 1 1 1 
1 0 1 0 0 1
```

As can be seen easily, `a` and `aSlicing` are the same arrays for python. However, the C function that reads the data in sees the data as kind of transposed. C regards aSliced as if it were

```
a.T.reshape((10,6))
```

Does anyone know why this error appears and how to properly circumvent it? Of course, transposing within the C code is easy. However, I want my program to be able to deal with both types of arrays.

I would prefer a solution within my C extension, i.e. useres of my extension shall not have to care about whether their input is "sliced" or not. Nevertheless, I tried to put a deep copy of `aSliced` into my extension - which had the same wrong result as `aSliced` had.

I am working with python 3.4 64bit, numpy 1.9.1, Win8 64bit and Visual Studio 10 64bit C compiler.

Comment: look at `.flags` or `.__array_interface__`.   Boolean indexing produces a copy, and in this case, it is `F_CONTIGUOUS`.

Comment: Thaks for the comment, @hpaulj! Would it be best to read this flag and depending on the outcome use a different way of reading the array memory? Or is there a different, more elegant way? I searched for a while but found it nowhere: How can I get the value of a flag from within C?

Comment: Docs on the array flags: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/c-api.array.html#array-flags

Answer (score 0):

As hpaulj pointed out, it is possible to figure out the memory structure using the flag `F_CONTIGUOUS`. I spent a lot of time trying to find a way to read this flag from within C. As far as I found out, it can be done with evaluating the value of `trials_array->flags % 2`. However, I did not find any reference with a clear explenation for this issue.

`trials_array->flags` is an integer number. The numpy flag constants `NPY_C_CONTIGUOUS`, `NPY_F_CONTIGUOUS`, etc. are integers which are powers of two. It seems to be true that the flag is set if the respective position in the binary representation of `trials_array->flags` is 1.

Even with knowing the memory structure it is not as trivial as I thought to read the array in. I found a *much easier* way to convert numpy arrays to C arrays: Use

```
char *myArray;
PyArrayObject *myArray_Numpy;

PyArray_AsCArray(&myArray_Numpy, (void *) &myArray, myArray_Numpy->dimensions, 2, PyArray_DescrFromType(NPY_BOOL));

//Do something with the array

PyArray_Free(myArray_Numpy, myArray);
```

I found an example for using these functions [here](http://mail.scipy.org/pipermail/numpy-discussion/2009-September/045367.html).